# Wc3 error: certificate invalid (google api): severe: prevents page rendering - what to do?

Tags: fonts, google-api, certificate, roboto

**Website development: desired a universal font** - chose to link to google online font resource (rightly or wrongly).

**Tested doc in W3C mobileOK Checker**.... it listed:

> Invalid certificates will be rejected by mobile browsers, de facto
>   preventing the rendering of the page. How? This usually means that the
>   certificate could not be retrieved or that the cryptographic algorithm
>   used for the key exchange is not widely supported. Where? Triggered by
>   https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:700.
>   Triggered by
>   https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700.
>   Triggered by
>   (3rd link)fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,900.

**Defacto prevents page rendering!**

I am aware that some Wc3 alerts are purely advisory, but this one is listed as severe.

Numerous sources suggested Roboto was good for browser coverage(?) but what to do?

Can I download the fonts to my site?

Is it a phantom problem that doesn't exist?

This must affect vast numbers of people, yet there is no info on stackoverflow (or anywhere).

Does anybody know the truth behind these apparent severe errors.... and what is the solution, when attempting to specify a universal font?

Answer (score 0):

> The mobileOK Checker could not retrieve some of the resources required to run the tests

Basically the mobileOK checker appears to not be configured properly. They don't provide enough info to know exactly why though.

The [SSL Report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=https%3A%2F%2Ffonts.googleapis.com) for https://fonts.googleapis.com shows it having support for a number of less secure features which generally means support for older browsers.

Since the error is only on fonts you don't need to worry. Worst case is the font won't load on some very old/miss-configured browser and that users sees their default font.

Comment: Thank you for setting my mind at ease there... My key concern was that I'm using a condensed font, whilst positioning for responsive... space is tight, so condensed seems the way forward.... at least I now know that most browsers will load these fonts - thanks again! (can't upvote you as I don't have the rep).

Comment: You should still be able to accept it even if you can't upvote.